# Как подключить Android Studio к NoSQL Amazon AWS?

Tags: android, sql, база-данных, android-studio

Вроде все делаю по инструкции, но все равно выбивает ошибки. Не удается импортировать:

```
import com.amazonaws.mobilehelper.config.AWSMobileHelperConfiguration;
import com.mysampleapp.R;
```

и

```
import com.amazonaws.mobile.AWSMobileClient;
```

Comment: Добавте сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет импорта, значит вы не импортировали зависимости.

Пропишите в `build.gradle`, что то типа такого:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'
}
```